# Avoiding duplicates in a random array output in php

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I'm currently working on a school project about php. The task is to design a website with some php navigation, a calculator, a truthsayer and some other functions. Now, I have a problem with the truthsayer I would like to get some help with. The truthsayer is a php randomizer that prints out a "truth" from an array I've set up. The truthsayer also prints out different amounts of truths depending on what number I give it. For example: If I type "3" into a box and presses enter, it will post three truths.

Now the problem: Since it completely randomizes it's output, I tend to get the same truths after each other. I for example ask for 10 truths, and 4-5 of them are the same as one of the other truths. Therefore I was wondering if anyone had an idea on how to make it avoid posting the same truth over and over again. Someone I know suggested a temporary removal of the truth from the array, but I'm not sure how I will make that work.

Any ideas? Much appreciated=P

My code:

```
<html>
<body>


<div id="Sannsigar">
<?php

if(isset($_POST["psc"])) {
$adder1 = $_POST["i1"];

$SannOutput= "";
    
    $Val = array("1=Ichi","2=Ni","3=San","4=Shi/Yon","5=Go","6=Roku","7=Nana","8=Hachi","9=Kyu","10=Jyu");
    
    switch ($adder1) {
        
        case "1" : {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$adder1; $x++) 
        {
        echo $Val[array_rand($Val)] . "<br>"; }
        "<br>";
        break;
        }
        
        case "2" : {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$adder1; $x++) 
        {
        echo $Val[array_rand($Val)] . "<br>"; }
        break;
        }
        
        case "3" : {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$adder1; $x++) 
        {
        echo $Val[array_rand($Val)] . "<br>"; }
        break;
        }
        
        case "4" : {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$adder1; $x++) 
        {
        echo $Val[array_rand($Val)] . "<br>"; }
        break;
        }
        
        case "5" : {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$adder1; $x++) 
        {
        echo $Val[array_rand($Val)] . "<br>"; }
        break;
        }
        
        case "6" : {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$adder1; $x++) 
        {
        echo $Val[array_rand($Val)] . "<br>"; }
        break;
        }
        
        case "7" : {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$adder1; $x++) 
        {
        echo $Val[array_rand($Val)] . "<br>"; }
        break;
        }
        
        case "8" : {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$adder1; $x++) 
        {
        echo $Val[array_rand($Val)] . "<br>"; }
        break;
        }
        
        case "9" : {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$adder1; $x++) 
        {
        echo $Val[array_rand($Val)] . "<br>"; }
        break;
        }
        
        case "10" : {
        for ($x=1; $x<=$adder1; $x++) 
        {
        echo $Val[array_rand($Val)] . "<br>"; }
        break;
        }
        
    
    default: {
    Echo "FEIL! Feil inndata. Oppgje eit tal mellom 1 og 10.";
    break;
    }
    
}

$Footer = fopen("Sannsigar/footer.php", "w");
fwrite ($Footer, "$adder1 sanning(ar) fr� Birger AS" . "<br>");
fclose($Footer);

}
?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've read that from the beginning. Then stuck. Then read again. Stuck. Tried from end to the beginning. No success. 3 'trues'? 10 'trues'? Random 'trues'? What is that? Can't understand your request, sorry

Comment: not related to the php side of it but isnt 7 = shichi in japanese?

Comment: @95husum ahhh :-) that makes sense.. and there i was thinking i was correcting the 'truthsayer' haha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define a `switch` case for each input. You can achieve the same thing using a little function.

```
function getRandom($adder1, $Val) {
    $randoms = range(0, $adder1-1);
    shuffle($randoms);
    if ($adder1 <= count($Val)) {
        foreach ($randoms as $r) {
            echo $Val[$r]."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The function can be called as below:

```
getRandom(3, $Val);
```

Sample Output:

```
9=Kyu
3=San
10=Jyu
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/56560)

Comment: @95husum: It was a silly mistake on my part. It's been fixed. Check the [updated demo](https://eval.in/56560).